# CountUp JS resulting in NAN using php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

While writing down this I know I am posibly posting a duplicate. But I realy don't see those examples help me and I realy dont get why this is error is showing ..

I am trying to include the project CountUp.js from Github

https://github.com/inorganik/countUp.js

Which eventualy worked (I am new to this so wassent all easy for me.. )

But for some reason this is showing up with the result NAN. Below is my code what am i doing wrong ??

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/countup.js/1.8.2/countUp.min.js'></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<?php
$cashinstore = 1000000;
$cashnewinstore = 2000000;

echo "<div>Current balance: &#127820;<div id=\"counter\" style=\"display:inline\">".htmlspecialchars(number_format($cashinstore,0,",","."))."</div>"
?>


<script>
function countup() {
  var options = {
    useEasing: true,
    useGrouping: true,
    separator: ".",
    decimal: ",",
    duration: 0.1,
  
    
  };

  let demo = new CountUp('counter', "<?php echo $cashnewinstore; ?>", options);
  if (!demo.error) {
    demo.start();
  } else {
    console.error(demo.error);
  }
}

countup();
</script>
```

Comment: You're outputting `$cashnewinstore` as a string. Lose the quotation marks. Outputting PHP directly into another language can be tricky and cause situations like this one. Personally I prefer to output all PHP values JS needs as a JSON encoded associative array. For example output`var globals = <?php echo json_encode(array('cashNewInStore' => $cashnewinstore ); ?>` in a `<script>` tag. This enables you to instantly see what the value is you're using and it keeps the rest of your JS clear of any PHP.

Comment: Adding that line to my script results in a HTTP ERROR 500..?

Comment: I don't think PHP is the cause of the problem here. I'm testing with hardcoded values and I still get NaN.

Comment: It seems like your problem is that you're using an old version. You're including 1.8.2, but you're following the syntax from the example for the 2.0.7 version.

Comment: Hmm. Ill check thank you

Comment: checking the linked file, that's the interface for this constructor: `new CountUp(idOrElement, startVal, endVal, decimalPlaces = 0, duration = 2, options = {})`